# Celery retried messages remain in same worker

Tags: python, celery

I had in the back of my mind the impression that if a celery worker gets a task , and it is retried - it remains in the worker's memory (with the eta) - and doesn't return to the queue.
resulting in that if a celery task is retried and the worker is busy working on different tasks , and that task eta arrives- it has to wait until it finishes processing the other tasks.

I tried looking in the documentation for something that is aligned with what I remembered , but I can't find anything.

what I did to try and check it is create two tasks.

```
@app.task(bind=True, name='task_that_holds_worker', rate_limit='4/m',
          default_retry_delay=5 * 60,
          max_retries=int(60 * 60 * 24 * 1 / (60 * 5)))
def task_that_holds_worker(self, *args, **kwargs):
    import time
    time.sleep(50000)

@app.task(bind=True, name='retried_task', rate_limit='2/m',
          default_retry_delay=10 * 60,
          max_retries=int(60 * 60 * 24 * 1 / (60 * 10)))
def retried_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.retry()
```

the simplest tasks , just to check that if a task is busy with other task - the retried task is not processed by another worker.

I then launched one worker - and triggered those two tasks in the following way:

```
from some_app import tasks
from some_app.celery_app import app

current_app = app.tasks

async_result = tasks.retried_task.delay()

import time
time.sleep(20)

async_result = tasks.task_that_holds_worker.delay()
```

the worker processed the retried task , and retried it, 
and then moved to the task that sleeps.
I then launched another worker and i can see that it is not getting the 'retried' task, only the first worker.

each worker launched was launced with `--prefetch-multiplier=1 --concurrency=1`
Is there something wrong with the way I reproduced this?
or is this the way a celery retried task behaves?

Thanks in advance!

- celery: 4.1.2
- Python: 3.6.2
- Rabbitmq Image: rabbitmq:3.6.9-management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is an issue with tasks with eta. the first available worker counts down until the task eta and doesn't release it back to the queue. (prefetch count is increased and ignored)

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2541

Answer (score 1):

There is an error with how you reproduced it.  Unless you have a special broker, celery will *always* requeue a task retry request back to the broker.  Workers do not retain any memory of which task they attempted, and there is no data added to the retry request that allows celery to route the task request back to the same worker.  There is no guarantee or assurance that the same worker will retry a task that it has seen before.  You can confirm this in the code for celery in `celery/app.task.py`

```
# get the signature of the task as called
S = self.signature_from_request(
    request, args, kwargs,
    countdown=countdown, eta=eta, retries=retries,
    **options
)

if max_retries is not None and retries > max_retries:
    if exc:
        # On Py3: will augment any current exception with
        # the exc' argument provided (raise exc from orig)
        raise_with_context(exc)
    raise self.MaxRetriesExceededError(
        "Can't retry {0}[{1}] args:{2} kwargs:{3}".format(
            self.name, request.id, S.args, S.kwargs))

ret = Retry(exc=exc, when=eta or countdown)
if is_eager:
    # if task was executed eagerly using apply(),
    # then the retry must also be executed eagerly.
    S.apply().get()
    if throw:
        raise ret
    return ret

try:
    S.apply_async()
except Exception as exc:
    raise Reject(exc, requeue=False)
if throw:
    raise ret
return ret
```

I've bolded the part where you can see how the retry works.  Celery gets the tasks request signature (this include the task name, and the arguments to the task, and sets the eta, countdown, and retries).  And then celery will simply call `apply_async`, which under the hood will just queue up a new task request to the broker.

Your sample did not work because celery workers will often pull more than one task request off of the broker, so what likely happened is that the first worker grabbed the task off of the broker before the second worker had come online.

Comment: Hey :) thank you for your response!
there is one thing i missed in my example that i think is crucial to it.
I set the prefetch count and concurrency of each of the workers to 1,
`worker -A some_app.celery_app -Q queue -l DEBUG --prefetch-multiplier=1 --concurrency=1`
I can see that the example is an 'apply_async' - i just can't seem to understand why the other worker didn't take my task?

Comment: Start both workers at the same time instead of starting one later than the other.

Comment: but if i do that i won't be able to create a situation where a retried task stays in a worker that is for sure a busy worker

Comment: Sure you can, just saturate both workers with a lot of tasks and sandwich a call to the exception task in between.

Comment: seems like i'm facing a different problem, i set the prefetch multiplier to 1 and the concurrency to 1 - i started many tasks as you suggested while one of them is a blocker task. the worker took the blocker task but took 6 tasks as well. seems like prefetch multiplier and concurrency doesn't affect the number of tasks taken from the queue? 
when i look at the channel in the rabbit ui - 
Global prefetch count=1
Messages unacknowledged=6

Comment: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2788 - here someone stated that a task with an eta act differently.

Comment: also here - https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1933 
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2541